# conda not getting initialize using ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible, anaconda

I am automating conda installation with ansible but the last step of getting the conda activated (the conda init ) getting failed.

I tried to run conda init as shell script and command module all failed.

**Code:**

```
---
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: true
    tasks:
     - name: Ansible copy file to remote server
       copy:
         src: ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
         dest: ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
     - name: Run the installer Anaconda
       command: bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b 
     - name: add path
       shell: export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
     - name: initialize conda
       shell: init conda
       args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

**Error:**

> - "stderr": "Expected single character argument.", "stderr_lines":

Comment: for which line it is showing error?

Comment: on initialize conda

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems you are executing wrong command. It should be "conda init"  instead of "init conda"
2. you can combine both shell task in one and can execute it. 
   Updated code is as follows:

```
---
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: true
    tasks:
     - name: Ansible copy file to remote server
       copy:
         src: ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
         dest: ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
     - name: Run the installer Anaconda
       command: bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh -b 

     - name: Add path and initialize conda
       shell: export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH && conda init
       args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable *PATH*, set by the *shell* module is available in this task (shell session) only. Try

```
shell: "export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH; init conda"
args:
  executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: fatal: [192.168.88.85]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH; init conda ", "delta": "0:00:00.009078", "end": "2019-05-25 17:18:19.938389", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-25 17:18:19.929311", "stderr": "Expected single character argument.", "stderr_lines": ["Expected single character argument."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}